# Feedback: Expired job postings

Tags: feature-request, status-bydesign, stack-overflow-jobs

When a job listing has expired, it would be far better to be informed of that when I click the Apply button than when I click Submit after filling in the form and writing a cover letter.

Comment: What happened? Did you fill out an application and then couldn't submit it because the job *just* expired?

Comment: @Patrice Fair enough.

Comment: Boy, what weird digression that turned into. @Makoto understands me exactly.

Comment: @Max, I had opened the job listing some days earlier but had not acted immediately.

Answer (score 1):

When a job listing expires, there is a notification displayed at the top of the page (screenshot below). It sounds like this job expired while you had the application window open or perhaps the page hadn't refreshed before you clicked 'apply'. 
[image]

Comment: Is there a grace period for submitting an application that was in process when the listing expires?

Comment: @JoeW Immediately after any application is submitted there is an 'undo' button displayed for 30 seconds. If a listing was expired, the application wont be sent to the employer so 'undo' would not be applicable in this case.

Comment: Not really sure how an existing feature that I didn't see (probably because I didn't refresh) makes my request something not worth considering. The lack of an Expired notice once I've clicked Apply and gone somewhere is a UX failure, whether you acknowledge it or not.

Comment: That's valuable feedback, @MikeC. What would you like to see happen if a job expired while you were filling out your coverletter?

Comment: @SaraChipps is the expiration time known? If I click Apply within eight hours of expiration, a warning "this listing will expire in [N] hours". It's true, I could click Apply one day and come back the next, just as I clicked on the listing one day and came back the next.

Comment: That makes sense, @MikeC, thank you. We'll keep an eye on this issue moving forward and maybe look into how often this is happening.